# (Prolog) the first solution from the list that satisfies the goal

Tags: prolog

I need to find the *first* element on the list which satisfies a user provided goal. I mean something like `maplist/2` but which succeeds when the goal can be applied to *at least one* element. `include/3` would be an option but I'm after a more optimal solution that can stop after finding the first element.

I think the interface could look like:

```
first(:Goal, List, First)
```

and it should be *semidet* in the [SWI-Prolog sense](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes).

It's fairly easy to code it but I'd prefer an existing rule. Is there a relevant rule in the "standard" libraries; I'm using SWI-Prolog.

Cheers,
  Jacek

Comment: I don't think there's a standard predicate that does this. But as you say, it would be very easy to code. I would probably write something like `include_item(:Goal, List, Item)` which succeeds for each `Item` in `List` that allows `:Goal` to succeed, then use `once/1` on the call to `include_item/3`. In effect, a version of `include/3` could be written as `include(Goal, List, Items) :- findall(X, include_item(Goal, List, X), Items).`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a standard predicate that does this. But as you say, it would be very easy to code. I would probably write something like this, which has a pattern like the `member/2` predicate:

```
includes_item(Goal, [X|_], X) :-
    call(Goal, X).
includes_item(Goal, [_|T], X) :-
    includes_item(Goal, T, X).
```

---

As @false indicates in the comments, this in fact can be more clearly written using `member/2`:

```
includes_item(Goal, List, Item) :-
    member(Item, List),
    call(Goal, Item).
```

---

`includes_item(:Goal, List, Item)` succeeds for each `Item` in `List` that satisfies `:Goal`. For example:

```
3 ?- includes_item('>'(3), [1,2,3,-2, 4, 5], X).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = -2 ;
false.
```

You can then use `once/1` to obtain only the first item without a choice point:

```
first(Goal, List, Item) :-
    once(includes_item(Goal, List, Item)).
```

And now you get:

```
4 ?- first('>'(3), [1,2,3,-2, 4, 5], X).
X = 1.

5 ?-
```

Comment: So why not `includes_item(Goal_1, Xs, X) :- member(X, Xs), call(Goal_1, X).`? It's the same but better readable.

Comment: Good, point. I coded it as your original `includes_item` but prefer the one with `member`. Indeed, clearer.